Prove that a set of formulas proves itself
Here is a formalization of an Axiom System for the Propositional Calculus from Mendelsons book "Introduction to mathematical logic":
Require Import List.
Require Import Coq.Program.Equality.
Import ListNotations.

(* Symbols of L theory *)
Parameter atom : Set.

Inductive formula : Type :=
| f_atom : atom -> formula
| f_not  : formula -> formula
| f_imp  : formula -> formula -> formula.

Notation "-, F" := (f_not F) (at level 75, right associativity).
Notation "F ~> G" := (f_imp F G) (at level 95, right associativity).

Inductive axiom : formula -> Prop :=
  | A1: forall A B, axiom (A ~> B ~> A)
  | A2: forall A B C, axiom ( (A ~> B ~> C) ~> (A ~> B) ~> (A ~> C) )
  | A3: forall A B, axiom ((-, B ~> -, A) ~> ((-, B ~> A) ~> B)).

Reserved Notation "Γ |-- l" (at level 98, right associativity).
Inductive proof_chain (Γ : list formula) : list formula -> Prop :=
  | pc_nil : Γ |-- []
  | pc_axiom : forall (A : formula) l, axiom A -> Γ |-- l -> Γ |-- A :: l
  | pc_in : forall (A : formula) (l : list formula), In A Γ -> Γ |-- l -> Γ |-- A :: l
  | pc_MP : forall (A B :formula) (l : list formula), In B l -> In (B ~> A) l -> Γ |-- l -> Γ |-- A :: l
where "Γ |-- l" := (proof_chain Γ l).

Now I am trying to prove the obvious statement:
Lemma self_proof: forall (Γ: list formula),
    Γ |-- Γ.
Proof.
  intros.
  induction Γ.
  * apply pc_nil.
  * apply pc_in.
    simpl. auto.

It is true because for every formula in Γ we can use pc_in constructor.
1 goal

a : formula
Γ : list formula
IHΓ : Γ |-- Γ
----------------------
a :: Γ |-- Γ

But now I am stuck: how to get rid of a formula at the beginning of a :: Γ to get the inductive hypothesis?

Generalise your lemma to Δ ++ Γ ⊢ Γ, then instantiate Δ at the empty list.

Lemma self_proof: forall (Γ: list formula),
    Γ |-- Γ.
Proof.
  intros Γ.
  enough (WTS : forall Γ', (forall A, In A Γ' -> In A Γ) -> Γ |-- Γ').
  { eapply WTS; eauto. }
  induction Γ' as [ | A' Γ' IH]; simpl; intros.
  - eapply pc_nil.
  - eapply pc_in; eauto.
Qed.


Explainations on the proof.

WTS means "want to show".

The tactic enough is something like assert but there is a difference.
By using assert (H : P)., we first prove P, and then use H for the original goal.
However, enough (H : P). we first prove the original goal with H, and then prove P.
Here, enough (WTS : forall Γ', (forall A, In A Γ' -> In A Γ) -> Γ |-- Γ'). is the same as assert (WTS : forall Γ', (forall A, In A Γ' -> In A Γ) -> Γ |-- Γ'); cycle 1.

eapply and eauto are similar to apply and auto, respectively. However, the formers work with existential variables.



What does the name "WTS" stand for? Can you post any link, explaining eapply and eauto tactics? I heard about them, but don't know, how they work.

enough is the same as assert?

@user4035 I've updated my answer.

That's a better generalisation than what I suggested!

@NaïmFavier Can you post you suggestion as another answer?
